# Error in charging a one-off payment in pinax-stripe module of django python

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments, pinax

I am developing an application in python in django framework where I have to charge one-off payment from the customers. I am using pinax-stripe module for payments(https://github.com/pinax/pinax-stripe).

When I charge the customer in my view like this:

```
#views.py
from pinax.stripe.models import *

if customer.can_charge():
    customer.charge(15.00) #charge
```

It gives me the the following error:

> Exception Type:   NameError
>
> Exception Value:   name 'customer' is not defined

I know there is something I need to import from pinax.stripe into my app's views.py. Does anyone know what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably look at the [getting started guide](http://pinax-stripe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started/)

It mentions that to create customers, you'd need code like

```
from pinax.stripe.actions import customers
customer = customers.create(user=new_user)
```

Edit

If a customer object already exists, you can try to get it with something like

```
customer = Customer.objects.get(user=relevant_user) # or similar
```

Comment: I tried your approach but still the same error I am afraid :(

Comment: Same but with from pinax.stripe.actions import customers added to the top. I init customers as they they signup, but i also did it manually now using ./manage.py init_customers

Comment: Just adding the import isn't enough, you need to define the customer variable. So either creating it like the second line above, or query the database to get it if it already exist.

Comment: I added this, but its giving the following error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pinax_stripe_customer_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) already exists.

Comment: Ok, so it already exists. Need to fetch it instead. Made an edit.

Comment: Ah that worked! Thanks a lot! :) I am marking your answer as correct but I am getting another error:  'Customer' object has no attribute 'charge'. Do you know where it it coming from?